# jquery validation for a form creaing by zend form

Tags: jquery, validation, zend-framework, client

I am able to validate a form in server side, but unable to do in client side. The form is creating by zend form. My code is like:

```
    $this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
    'label' => 'Name:',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'span12'
    ));
    $this->addElement('text', 'phone', array(
    'label' => 'Phone:',
    'required' => true,
    'class' => 'span12'
    ));
   $this->addElement('submit', 'save', array(
    'ignore' => true,
    'label' => 'Submit',
    'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
    ));
```

Please let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var name = $('input[name="name"').val();
        if (name == '' || typeof name == 'undefined') {
            alert('Please provide name');
            return false;
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: how to use validate() method for validating?

Comment: no jquery validate(). I think its for client side validation. But for me it is showing typeerror $(...).validate is not a function.

Comment: Ok, you can refer this http://codeutopia.net/blog/2008/04/04/client-side-validation-with-zend_form/

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a tool that automatically creates client side validation (using the jQuery Validation Plugin) from a given Zend_Form. All you have to do is to use something like this is your view:

```
echo $this->form->render();
echo $this->ZQueryFormValidation($this->form);
```

A short example plus links to the manual and the GitHub page can be found here: http://www.web-punk.com/2014/01/automatically-generate-client-side-form-validation-from-server-side-form-validation-zend-form-to-jqueryvalidation/